# El procedimiento o la función X esperaba el parámetro X, que no se ha especificado

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Contexto:
Me arroja el siguiente error al momento de presionar el botón donde tengo alojado esa información
El error me empezó a salir cuando estaba creando textbox para buscar por Rut(Numero identificador) y Nombre:

Procedimiento Almacenado CE_ObtenerTecnicos_JP:

```
SELECT  tec_rut_tec,
        tec_dig_ver,
        tec_ide_tec,
        tec_nom_tec,
        tec_tel_fij,
        tec_tel_mov ,
        tec_cor_ele ,
        PAR.par_des_par AS estado,
        tec_usr_res 
FROM TEC
INNER JOIN PAR ON PAR.par_cod_tab = 1 AND PAR.par_cod_par= TEC.tec_cod_est
WHERE 
    tec_rut_tec  LIKE CASE Convert(varchar(18),@Rut) WHEN  0 THEN '%' ELSE Convert(varchar(18),@Rut) + '%' END
AND tec_nom_tec  LIKE CASE @Nombre                  WHEN '' THEN '%' ELSE @Nombre + '%' END
AND tec_cod_est =    CASE @Estado WHEN '-1' THEN tec_cod_est ELSE @Estado END

ORDER BY tec_rut_tec
```

Codigo Capa Negocios(Donde Llamo a la capa que trae los datos):

```
 public static DataTable ObtenerTecnicos_JP(Decimal Rut, String Nombre, int Estado, string CadenaConexion)
        {
            SqlCommand _comando = AccesoDatos.Obtener_Tecnicos_JP(Rut ,Nombre, Estado, CadenaConexion);
            _comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            return AccesoDatos.EjecutarComando(_comando);
        }
```

Codigo Capa AccesoDatos(Donde mando a buscar el procedimiento y sus @)

```
  public static SqlCommand Obtener_Tecnicos_JP(Decimal Rut, String Nombre, int Estado, string CadenaConexion)
        {
            string _cadenaconexion = CadenaConexion;
            SqlConnection _conexion = new SqlConnection(_cadenaconexion);
            SqlCommand _comando = new SqlCommand("CE_ObtenerTecnicos_JP", _conexion);
            _comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rut",Rut);
            _comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nombre",Nombre);
            _comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("Estado",Estado);
            _comando.Connection.Close();
            return _comando;
        }
```

Funcion del boton "Buscar por Rut o Nombre"

```
 public void BuscaListaTecnicos() 
        {

            Rut = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRut.Text)) ? Convert.ToDecimal(txtRut.Text) : 0; ;
            Nombre = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNombre.Text)) ? txtNombre.Text : "";
            Estado = Convert.ToInt32(Drpestado.SelectedValue);
            DataTable Buscar = new DataTable();
            Buscar = PreparaAcceso.ObtenerTecnicos_JP(Rut,Nombre,Estado, cadenaConexion);
            GrillaTecnico.DataSource = Buscar;
            GrillaTecnico.DataBind();
        
        
        }
```

Como dato adicional el error me lo despliega cuando esta llenando la tabla **ayuda!**

Comment: cuando decis parametro X , que parametro sale en el error? y podemos ver como esta declarado el SP?